# How to install ttf fonts?

Tags: software-installation, fonts

I want to install a font from true type of font of my own. where should I install my font in ubuntu?

Answer (score 58):

Copy the `.ttf` file and paste it inside `~/.fonts` folder, i.e. `/home/username/.fonts` folder. Create one if you don't already have one.

Now run:

```
fc-cache -fv
```

from a terminal. You should now be able to see the new fonts in your editor/application. (editor/application might need a restart)

Comment: Note: but don't use sudo since in this case you placed the font in a folder in your own home directory. See the link at the top for further details.

Answer (score 10):

Double click on the `TTF` file and select the `Install` button.

Comment: You will find Windows ttf fonts in Windows\Fonts. Btw, it is legal to use Windows native fonts in Linux if both OS's are on the same machine.